# BroadcastReceiver cause crash inside AndroidService

Tags: android, service, connection, broadcastreceiver, runtimeexception

I'm working on AndroidService, where every 5 minutes a network call is made to search new data from database. I have implemented `BroadcastListener` to listen for constant connection inside service, but the app is crashing everytime.

Error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } in com.test.service.MyService$1@d3df904

Globally declared:

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver;
```

Code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if(ConnectionStatus.isConnected(MyService.this)){
                  //some work
            }
            else {
                //some task
            }
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    return START_STICKY;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`onCreate` happens before `onStartCommand` so you are trying to register a broadcast receiver with a null receiver. Remove the register from `onCreate` and it should work.

Comment: I'm still getting the same `RuntimeException`, I removed also

Comment: Also where should register receiver ?

Comment: Do you unregister it when the service is destroyed? I have pretty much the exact same code in a service that works fine.